# SMTP not including from address in sent mail

Tags: email, smtp, go

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I can't seem to get smtp to include the from address when using smtp.SendMail.
I'm using https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/SendingMail as an outline.

Have been struggling to do so for hours, so any help would be great.

I can send messages fine, just the from address seems to stay blank; which doesn't work well with gmail and etc, as they just consider it spam.

Is the from address meant to be something special or something? (first time doing this, so might just be missing some domain knowledge)....

I've noted that the username in smtp.PlainAuth is not the same as the from address in the example given; I've been using the same string for both..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The body that the SMTP module is expecting is actually both user supplied headers and the body content.  They're separated by two newlines.

So the body you supply to smtp should look something like this:

```
From: Me <me@me.com>
Subject: This is a test email from me

Hello this is a test email!
```

Comment: Hurrah, it works! Now I can finally go to sleep I think. Cheers. Have to say, that was a bit confusing. Any chance you know why it seems to be emailing two messages at once though lol? jks. Will have to figure that out when I wake up methinks.